# Can I use the testfor command to detect players above a height?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to have a testfor command detect player above a height?

Like this: `/testfor @e[x=5, z=5, y=256, dx=5, dz=5, dy=∞]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting situation. The command you have stated is useful when the aim is to detect a player **below** a certain y-level.

The dy parameter simply means the difference in y value that the player can be from the y parameter, that is the one set to 256. What you have written in your question will create a point at the y level you choose, then scan both up by infinite blocks and down by infinite blocks. Unfortunately, this doesn't work as you can not to choose to only search above a level as greater than and less than operations aren't supported.

The reason this can be down below a certain level is that you can create a point at y=0 and then set dy to be the lowest y value you want the player to be, this works naturally as players never have a reason to be below y=0.

I am not sure what the purpose of this is for, but what I recommend is that instead of trying to detect players above 256, I assume deliberately the build height, you can try to prevent it. However, I am not sure your purpose and, therefore, not sure how easy that would be.